# How can one build dynamic sitemaps in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

How can one build dynamic sitemaps in ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1):

- [Sql Sitemap Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163657.aspx)
- [Physical file sitemap provider](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133925/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/020106-1.aspx)

You can take a look at these for ideas or just reuse them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact context (Forms or MVC, etc), but here are a couple of resources you can take a look at. You have several options, and I don't yet have the rep to post multiple links, so I'll post the google search link I did and call  out a few links I found that could work for you.

http://www.bing.com/search?q=ASP.NET+Dynamic+sitemap&form=QBRE&qs=n&sk=&sc=1-23

- Scan your site folder structure (using LINQ) and auto-gen a sitemap - 3rd Link (Creating Dynamic ASP.NET SiteMap using LINQ)
- Implementing your own SiteMapProvider (MDSN) - 6th link (Implementing ASP.NET Site-Map Providers)
- Implement and override the StaticSiteMapProvider - 4th Link (Adding dynamic nodes to ASP.NET site maps at runtime by deriving from ...)
- SiteMapProvider for MVC - mvcsitemap.codeplex.com
- Simple implementation using RouteTable values (MVC) - 10th link (Dynamic sitemap in ASP.NET MVC - Stack Overflow)

I hope these help, or point you inthe right direction. Feel free to comment with more details if you're looking for something more specific.